# Compile Tor Browser on Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, ubuntu, debian, source-code, build

I have seen a ticket opened about this on tor bug tracker, but no progress for over a year on the Tor Browser being available on arm processors. I have setup firefox with a proxy to use Tor but that is not safe because the browser itself leaks to much info. So I am asking for help if this is the right place to ask how to compile the Tor Browser on RasPi 2 on Debian/Ubuntu. Just some simple instructions for me to follow so I can compile from source, or is there an easier way?

Comment: If you use Firefox (Iceweasel) make sure you go to about:config and change the network.proxy.socks_remote_dns from false to true, by default your DNS queries are leaked over clearnet. I just wanted to leave this as a comment but I don't have the reputation for it as I don't actually have much of a solution to your question other than pointing you to https://www.torproject.org/docs/debian.html.en#source

Answer (score 1):

Speaking from experience, this is not currently possible.

During the compiling process, the make script will download some binaries that are only built for X86 and not for ARM and therefore the compilation wil fail every time.

The Tor developers plan on releasing a version for Tor Browser for ARM in the future, but there is no ETA.

Your best option at the current time is to download the Tor application and apply it to Firefox/Iceweasel.

Comment: Do you have a ticket-link for that? The link from Andrew is not valid (closed/moved) anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Tor Browser does not work on ARM as of this time.

https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/12631

TOR ticket tracker for porting to ARM hasn't had much traction at all.

I wouldn't expect this project to be ported to arm anytime soon.

Note: tor is available on raspberry pi. This is for running a relay. This is different from the tor browser.

Answer (score -1):

On all raspberry pi's, I have found that downloading the source and then running the following commands

```
cd your/source/directory
sudo ./configure && sudo make
```

If all goes well, this will install TOR from source.

Note: You may need some external libraries in order for this to work. I needed libevent and libopenssh

Then just run tor from the command line like so

```
tor
```